# Large .PDF Files Not Uploading To MySQL Database as Medium BLOB Via PHP, Files under 2MB Work Fine

Tags: php, mysql, apache, blob

I am developing a PHP script for uploading .PDF documents as medium BLOBs into a MySQL database via PHP.  The script also allows users to search for files and open/download them but I do not think that part of the script is relevant to my issue.  The script works fine with files less than 2 MB but as soon as I try and upload a file that is more than 2 MB nothing is going into my content(Medium BLOB) column and there is no value for the mime type.  I have already tried increasing the max_packet_size for the MySQL server to 4 MB from its default value of 1 MB.  I have also updated php.ini to the correct values, I think.  I set upload_max_size to 4MB, post_max_size to 4 MB, and memory_limit to 16 MB.  I haven't really experimented with the max_input_time though because it is defaulted to 60 seconds which seems like plenty considering this script is for an internal application on an intranet.

I have also tried to catch errors from the PDO object in my script with errorInfo() and errorCode() and both through 0s (no error).

Here is the upload section of my script:

```
if ($key == 'upload')
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $_SESSION['upload'] = $value;

    if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'])
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
        $docType = $_POST['docType'];
        $netKey = $_POST['netKey'];
        $fp       = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content  = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $content  = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);

        $_SESSION['filetype'] = $fileType;

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }
        $sqlCheck = "SELECT id, name, documentType, networkKey FROM upload WHERE active='1'";
        foreach ($dbh->query($sqlCheck) as $row)
        {
            if (($row['name'] == $fileName) && ($row[networkKey] == $netKey) && ($row['documentType'] == $docType)) 
            {
                $_SESSION['updateRow'] = $row['id'];
            }

        }

        if ($_SESSION['updateRow'])
            {
                $deactivateDuplicate = "UPDATE upload SET active = 0, modifiedBy = '".strtoupper($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])."', modifiedDate = Now() WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['updateRow']."' AND active ='1'";
                $dbh->query($deactivateDuplicate);
                $_SESSION['sql'] = "SELECT id, name, documentType, type, size, networkKey, modifiedBy, modifiedDate, active FROM upload WHERE active = '1'";
                $_SESSION['uploadSearch'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['updateRow'] = 0;
            }
            $values = "'".$fileName."','".$docType."','".$fileType."','".$content."','".$fileSize."','".$netKey."','".strtoupper($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])."', Now(), 1";
            $sqlUpload = "INSERT INTO upload (name, documentType, type, content, size, networkKey, modifiedBy, modifiedDate, active) VALUES (".$values.")";
            $dbh->query($sqlUpload);

            $_SESSION['sql'] = "SELECT id, name, documentType, type, size, networkKey, modifiedBy, modifiedDate, active FROM upload WHERE active = '1'";
            $_SESSION['uploadSearch'] = 1;


    }
}
```

And Here is the front end of the application showing that a smaller file works and a larger file does not.  The file sample.pdf is less than 1 MB and the file test.pdf is 2.5 MB.

http://www.imagechicken.com/viewpic.php?p=1255628359017775300&x=png

I would have used img tags but alas I am a new user and not allowed.

The next thing I am going to look for is a setting in Apache that limits file sizes.  I am new to LAMP so any tips would be great.
Thanks

Comment: I am still having an issue with this.  It appeared to be working after I did what was recommended in this thread.  I set the max_allowed_packet setting in MySQL to 4M and the post and upload values in php.ini to more than adequate values.  

The problem I am having now is that the files appear to upload but they are still capped at 1M which is evident when I try to download them.  Within the $_FILES array the file is the right size but after the file is intersted to the MySQL database the content is truncated to 1 MB, even though the size column still gives the correct size.  Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually fixed the issue.  I changed all of the values that were recommended here in php.ini and my.cnf but I also needed to change a setting for PDO.

I changed:
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE (integer)
Maximum buffer size. Defaults to 1 MiB.

This has to be set when the PDO object is created to work though.  All is good now.

Answer (score 4):

YOu might be running up against the limitations of the HTTP request (which I think is 4MB), or your HTTP request might be timming out.  I have run into this issue before.  You might want to look @ your php.ini file for maximum upload size.

Disclaimer: I am not a PHP developer :D

Comment: +1 - this is most likely a PHP configuration issue, not a MySQL issue

Comment: I think you ll have to "stream" files, but I never did this before, especially not with PHP and/or MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You might be running into a mySQL limit.

Run the following in mySQL:

```
show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'
```

That will show you your current setting.
The default is 1047552 bytes.

This can be changed with your my.cnf file.
Simply add

```
set-variable = max_allowed_packet=2M
```

or what ever size is required and restart mySQL.

**EDIT**:
What about

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="xxx" />
```

Might that be part of the problem?

Comment: I have already had the database administrator update max_allowed_packet to 4M.

Comment: I will check out my input at work.  What exactly could be causing the problem though.

Comment: Good call Jason.  I had the value set at '20000000' which would obviously be the problem.  However, after I changed the value to '160000000' which is more than adequate the file isn't going into the database.  It is like the query isn't being performed at all.

Comment: Just had to restart apache.  Good call, I forgot all about that.

Answer (score 2):

So to recap all the things I believe I had to set in order to allow file uploads >1MB on something I was working on:

### php.ini

- Changed `post_max_size` (I wanted 15MB file uploads, so I set it to `20M` just in case)
- Changed `upload_max_filesize` to `15M`
- Left `max_execution_time` at `60`
- Left `max_input_time` at `60`
- Left `default_socket_timeout` at `60`

### my.ini

- Changed `max_allowed_packet` to `15M`

### PHP Code

- changed my PDO call to:

  `new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password,  array (PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE=>15*1024*1024))`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this on shared hosting (where you can't make changes to MySQL conf files, etc), Google 'mysqli prepared statements'.

This allows you to upload large queries in predefined byte chunks, circumventing any buffer restrictions.